# NTFS Compression Apply changes to this folder only

Tags: ntfs, compression

please can anyone tell me what is the difference between Apply changes to this folder only or Apply changes to this folder, subfolders and files when using ntfs compression ?!

i tried the  Apply changes to this folder only and it didn't do anything , it just changed the color of the folder itself ! not reducing any space !

when using the second option it compresses the folder and its content and it reduces the space ... so can anyone tell me what is the difference ?!

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

When you select 'Apply changes to this folder only' then any new file created directly under that folder will be compressed but any file that is correctly there or that is copied/moved into it will not be compressed and any files under any subfolders will not be compressed.